# How to open "My account" of Google Play Store programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play

I want to open up "**My account**" page of Google Play Store from my app by sending an intent.

I know how to open specific app's product details page in Google play store ([Android developers: Linking to Your Products](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play.html))

such as:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+appName)));
```

But now I want is to open "**My account**" to redirect user to check/adjust their payment methods or order history.

Is there any way to open "My account" page programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will work for all cases, but I had the same requirement and I solve it creating an intent to the account URL "https://play.google.com/store/account".

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/account");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.addFlags(
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK
);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the list of ways by which Google Play Store can be called using Intent :

https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play.html

Comment: I know this already, but it is not what I asked. Still thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but this can be helpful for others.

You have to change the market link like this The link: `market://search?q=pub:<publisher_name>`

And then you can use it in your code.

One more thing use `try catch` so if any user doesn't have store installed in his device still visit the link and also prevent the app from crashing.

```html
try{

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:<publisher_name>")));

}catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

// If the market is not available in the store.
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=<publisher_name>")));

}
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks